# Asking for User Name or Unique Identity before OAUTH/OpenID-Connect

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, google-openidconnect

I am building a website that uses OAuth2.0 and OpenId-Connect (of some third party vendor) to authenticate user.

Before redirecting the user to the vendor's OAuth page, I am not asking the user to enter a unique UserID on my website, I was thinking of using the user's emailid that I receive as a part of IDToken after the Authorization process is done, as the user's User Name(unique identity) for my Website.

But the OpenID specification here
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims

says that emailid is optional and may not be returned.

So the questions is, is it a standard practice to ask the User to provide with a unique name (that I can use as user's identity on my website), before I initiate the OAUTH/OpenID-Connect process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **sub** claim must be unique per **iss**uer. [Required Claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) will always be present. You can use the iss + sub to uniquely identify users.

Comment: Thanks, but i will not be able to use this as a username , to display when user logs in right. I will have to ask him for a userid

Comment: Yes, you can ask them to create a user ID for your website. It doesn't have to be unique. It can be their email. You don't need to send this information to the authentication provider.

Answer (score 0):

To add more information, every OpenID connect provider need to provide a /userinfo endpoint to fetch the users information using access token.

here is the specification
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo